# Is there a way to vary AutoLayout Constraints for iPad Pro?

Tags: ios, ipad, autolayout, interface-builder, size-classes

I have a view with several subviews that are vertically spaced within the parent view.  All the subviews have constant height, top spacing, and bottom spacing.  The parent view's height does not change, and is equal to the sum of all these constraints.  I'm using varied constraints for size classes so that these subviews have different heights/spacing for iPhone vs iPad.  But when I switch to viewing it on iPad Pro, there's way too much space.  I want to make some of the heights larger just on iPad Pro.  I can't figure out a way to do this in IB.  Is there a way?  Or do I have to resort to programmatically reading the parent view's size and changing the constraints from there?

Comment: do you mean iPad Pro 9.7, iPad Pro 12.9 or both?

Comment: 12.9 inch. The 9.7 has the same measurements as the iPad Air, but sinve the 12.9 inch is in the same size class as the others I can't find a way to vary the constraints for /just/ that one.

Comment: Mostly its wRhR for all the iPads. Either you can set the constraints constants programmatically or you can use constraints like pin it to top bottom etc so that space is covered (purely based on requirements).